# Entityframework code based config

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to get rid of the App.config with its EntityFramework (v6) settings and move it into code (Don't want to deploy the config with connection string and password).

Following exception is thrown on opening: `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.`

I'm using sqlite3 db with encryption and database first entity model.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DatabaseConfiguration))]
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
{
    public TestEntities () :
        base((DatabaseConfiguration.GetConnectionString("TestEntities", @"\\\\ABT\01_Tools\Test\DB\test.db", "someDummyPw")))
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class SQLiteConnectionFactory:IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
    }
}

public class DatabaseConfiguration:DbConfiguration
{
    public DatabaseConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SQLiteConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        //SetProviderFactory("System.Data.EntityClient", EntityProviderFactory.Instance);

        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string efModelName, string databaseFilePath, string password)
    {
        // Initialize the connection string builder for the underlying provider.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = databaseFilePath,
            Password = password
        };

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SQLite.EF6";

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = string.Format(@"res://*/Model.{0}.csdl|res://*/Model.{0}.ssdl|res://*/Model.{0}.msl", efModelName);

        return entityBuilder.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: InnerEx: `unable to open database file`